# How to download objects from your bucket in cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, bucket

Unable to download the image from bucket from the google cloud console. Is there any other way to download the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods to this.
Kindly follow the steps below:

Method 1 :-

1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the Cloud Storage Browser page.
2. In the list of buckets, click on the name of the bucket that contains the object you want to download.
   The bucket details page opens, with the Objects tab selected.
3. Navigate to the object, which may be located in a folder.
4. Click the more actions menu associated with the object.
5. Select Download.

Method 2 :-
Use the gsutil cp command.

`gsutil cp gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME SAVE_TO_LOCATION`

Where:
`BUCKET_NAME` is the name of the bucket containing the object you are downloading.
`OBJECT_NAME` is the name of object you are downloading.
`SAVE_TO_LOCATION` is the local path where you are saving your object.

Comment: Can you please refer the link?

Comment: Please find below the link:              
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#gsutil